# What does the "PHP Manual" says?

Tags: php

I understand that question like that one could sound a little bit absurdly, but it disturbs me already for a pretty long time and I haven't succeeded to find an answer myself.

The issue is in PHP's official function reference.
Can somebody explain me what does " [, int $blablabla ]" means in function's prototype?

For example, here how it comes in php.net:

> array str_split ( string $string [, int $split_length = 1 ] )

Why does the comma sign comes after the bracket? What does it supposed to mean?
And why the hell there is no comma after "string $string" parameter?

I really appreciate if someone could help me to resolve that kind of a mosaic... 
Tnx.

Comment: It's standard notation to denote optional parameter. It's used not just in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

It's an optional parameter. Any parameter listed between brackets are optional.

Comment: and since the parameter is optional, the comma is optional unless you include the optional parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the particular argument is optional, and the value after the `=` is the default value.

In this case, `$split_length` is optional, and if you call `str_split` with only 1 argument, `$split_length` will automatically pass as 1.